# Date bookmarklet needs leading zero on single digit months and days

Tags: javascript, date, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet I use to check daily log files. However the bookmarklet I use only delivers the month and day in single digits, however the log files use double digits.

For example my bookmarklet delivers:
http://url/log/2009-5-4_localcontrol-story.log,
while the log file actually lives at:
http://url/log/2009-05-04_localcontrol-story.log

Below is my current code:

```
javascript:d=new%20Date();window.open("http://url/log/"+d.getFullYear()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+(d.getDate())+"_localcontrol-story.log",%20"_self");
```

Can you tell me an adaptation to this so I get my month and date in 2 digit format with the leading zero if necessary?

Answer (score 10):

it's kind of a pain, but what I've done is to do stuff like this:

```
("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

(add a leading zero, and `slice(-2)` takes the last 2 characters)